# Como obter o valor sem máscara de um MaskedTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou usando um `MaskedTextBox` para formatação de documentos.

Ele está funcionando perfeitamente, mas como faço para obter o valor digitado no campo sem que a máscara esteja presente?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Solução

Se for por exemplo uma data digitada no `MaskedTextBox` com o valor '01/01/1991' e você quiser pegar somente 01011991 seria a melhor forma assim, inclusive serve isso para qualquer tipo independente da mascara.

**Código:**

```
maskedTextBox1.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals; // tira a formatação
label1.Text = maskedTextBox1.Text; //texto não formatado
maskedTextBox1.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludePromptAndLiterals; // retorna a formatação
```

**Imagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Uma sugestão seria utilizar Métodos Extensivos:

**Como:**
Crie uma arquivo com esse código, igualzinho.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    public static class Methods
    {
        public static string TextNoFormatting(this MaskedTextBox _mask)
        {
            _mask.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
            String retString = _mask.Text;
            _mask.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludePromptAndLiterals;
            return retString;
        }
    }
}
```

**Utilização:**

```
label1.Text = maskedTextBox1.TextNoFormatting();
```

*Perceba que a codificação ficou mais limpa*.

**Referências:**

- [C# 3.0 – Novidades – Extension Methods](http://www.adrianobertucci.com/2008/03/c-3-0-novidades-extension-methods/)
- [70-483 - DotNet CSharp - Métodos extensivos](http://marsosi.blogspot.com.br/2013/08/metodos-extensivos.html)

Comment: Legal! Boa alternativa!

Comment: @MatheusBessa, vlw, a sua também é muito boa...

Answer (score 1):

No lugar do texto, você pode utilizar o replace indicando o caractere a ser tirado e o que será reescrito nele, no caso nada ("").

Exemplo de um campo de CEP:

```
    mtxtbCep.Text.Replace("-","");
```

Ou:

```
    mtxtbCep.Text.Replace("-",String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução que conheço para esse tipo de problema é usando `Replace` ou `Remove`

```
string data = "22/04/2014";
data = data.Replace("/", string.Empty); /* parâmetros: Caractere antigo e o substituto dele, no caso uma string vazia. */
data = data.Remove(2, 1).Remove(4,1); /* parâmetros: Índice e a quantidade de caracteres que quero remover a partir daquele Índice */
```